# What constitutes generic dynamics, and how is it different from a fully random function?

Tags: complexity-theory, random-quantum-circuit

What constitutes generic dynamics? And how is it different from a fully random function?

From what I understand, a fully random function is one that is "Haar" random. And generic dynamics, at least colloquially, sounds like the same thing.

This statement appears in PRL 116, 170502 (2016): [Efficient Quantum Pseudorandomness](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/115397/PhysRevLett.116.170502.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say a "generic dynamics" is any dynamics? Probably referring to a generic *unitary* dynamics here though. A random function is, well, a random function. I'm not sure I understand the question. A "dynamics" refers to a type of physical evolution, so they are talking about how hard it is to distinguish the output of a generic system from the output of a random function